# Duplicate Entries in code coverage report

Tags: code-coverage, chutzpah

I've added few JS test files and added below mentioned references. In some files I've added smaller case letters in some JS files camel case one.(as mentioned below)

But while running code coverage from visual studio, the report contains two entries with same name.

```
    ///<reference path="/../frontendtools.webui/viewmodels/colorboxviewmodel.js"/>
    ///<reference path="/../FrontEndTools.WebUI/ViewModels/ColorBoxViewModel.js"/>
```

**OUTPUT BELOW:**

```
 3.C:\Users\b-nave\Downloads\FrontEndTools_buildserver\FrontEndTools\frontendtools.webui\viewmodels\colorboxviewmodel.js 11.11 %

 6.C:\Users\b-nave\Downloads\FrontEndTools_buildserver\FrontEndTools\FrontEndTools.WebUI\ViewModels\ColorBoxViewModel.js 100 % 9/9
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
-Naren

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug, please file a issue on chutzpah.codeplex.com and attach a zip file container a full repro of the issue.

Thanks!